# Get the user's email address and first name and last name after Google+ Sign In on Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I am working on an Android app and I am implementing Google+ Sign.

I've got it authenticating fine, however, I want to get the user first name, last name and email address.

I am using the following to try and get the name of the user, however, this only gets me the display name, not the first and last name separately which I've managed to do via Google+ Signin for the web.

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null)
        {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            Log.d("Display Name", currentPerson.getDisplayName());
}
```

The second problem, I am not able to get the email out of the response. If I debug the app and look at the response, I can see my email address, but for some reason in the code it just loops round and misses my email so returns null.

Below is the code for the email retrieval.

```
final String account = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
                    String sAccessToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(SignIn.this, account,
                            "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read");

                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + sAccessToken);

                    String content = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),
                            Charsets.UTF_8));

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(content))
                    {
                        JSONArray emailArray = new JSONObject(content).getJSONArray("emails");

                        for (int i = 0; i < emailArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)emailArray.get(i);

                            if (obj.getString("type") == "account")
                            {
                                return obj.getString("value");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UserRecoverableAuthException ex)
                {
                    startActivityForResult(ex.getIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN_GET_EMAIL);
                    Log.e("SignIn", ex.toString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e("SignIn", ex.toString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (urlConnection != null)
                    {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected  void onPostExecute(String info)
            {
                registerUserFromGooglePlusSignIn(info);
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

In onConnected

```
Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
String firstName = person.getName().getGivenName();
String lastName = person.getName().getFamilyName();
```

Check for more fields
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Name

Answer (score 2):

in on connected you need

```
Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

String name = person.getDisplayName(); //full name
Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) //email
```

the display name is the first and last name

Comment: Thanks I wanted them as separate variables, in the Javascript library for my web app, I've been able to get them out separetely, If I use the display name for Android I would then need to split the string, I know technically shouldn't be a problem, but thought if its available in javascript then it should be in android as well

Comment: the android api does not give separate values for just the first name and the last name

Comment: Ah ok cheers. I guess in that case then the only problem I have is the with the email address retrieval

Answer (score 1):

```
//After the signing we are calling this function
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        //If the login succeed
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Getting google account
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            String name=acct.getDisplayName();

            String email=acct.getEmail();

            Log.d("namegoogle",name);
            Log.d("emailgoogle",email);
            edit_signin_emailid.setText(email);

            String fullname = acct.getDisplayName();
            String[] parts = fullname.split("\\s+");
            Log.d("Length-->",""+parts.length);
            if(parts.length==2) {
                String firstname = parts[0];
                String lastname = parts[1];
                Log.d("First-->", "" + firstname);
                Log.d("Last-->", "" + lastname);
                AppController.setStringPref("firstnamebook", firstname);
                AppController.setStringPref("lastnamebook", lastname);

                Log.d("FirstApp", "" + AppController.getStringPref("firstnamebook"));
                Log.d("LastApp", "" + AppController.getStringPref("lastnamebook"));
            }
            else if(parts.length==3){
                String firstname = parts[0];
                String middlename = parts[1];
                String lastname = parts[2];
                Log.d("First-->", "" + firstname);
                Log.d("Last-->", "" + lastname);
                AppController.setStringPref("firstnamebook", firstname);
                AppController.setStringPref("lastnamebook", lastname);
            }


        }
    }
```